# Grouping months from a date column and adding quantities for all months

Tags: sql

I have a table named 'Orders' with 'entry_date' [datatype: datetime2(7)] as the date when the order was made. Corresponding to this date, I have a column named 'order_amt' [datatype: money]which stores the amount of money for which the order was made.The table also has 'refund_date' [datatype: datetime2(7)] and 'refund_amt' storing a what date a refund is made and what's the amount.
I have to select the total revenue[order_amt-refund_amt] for each month of 2015.

P.S: I am new to SQL, and also Stackoverflow.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Suppose an order was placed in December 2015, but the refund happened in 2016.  Do you want to count the refund amount in a 2015 calculation or should it be treated as zero?

Comment: It should be treated as 0 for 2015. Thanks Tim

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I am using SQL Server management studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime2` is a SQL Server type as far as I know.  If so, then you can try the following query:

```
DECLARE @start_date Date, @end_date DATE
SET @start_date = '2015-01-01'
SET @end_date = '2015-12-31'

SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, entry_date) AS month,
       SUM(order_amt - refund_amt) AS total_revenue
FROM Orders
WHERE entry_date >= @start_date AND entry_date <= @end_date
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, entry_date)
```

**Notes:** `DATEPART(MONTH, entry_date)` extracts the month from the `entry_date` column, which is what you want to use to group.  And the `@start_date` and `@end_date` variables specify the bounds to use for the `entry_date`.

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply. Wouldn't the refund_date be taken into consideration.

Comment: Also, how would the answer change if I have to declare and use variables for the start and end date ranges?

Comment: How do you want to define an order's year?  Does the refund also have to occur in 2015 in order for that order to be counted?

Comment: No, there is no limitation for the refund date on the year its made. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select datepart(month,entry_Date) as month, 
sum(order_amt-coalesce(refund_amt,0))) as total_amount
from orders
where entry_date>='20150101' and entry_date<'20160101' 
group by datepart(month,entry_Date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I not have to take the refund date into account?